# How does one implement Google Federated Login using dotnetopenauth

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

From what I read, Google Federated Login is OpenID and OAuth together. I've read the samples included with dotnetopenauth (theres a Gmail Contacts one in there) and sort of get it.

What is freaking me out, then, is if Google Federated Login is a combination of these two protocols, how on earth am I supposed to implement it when the samples are either one protocol or the other.

Anyone want to shed some light on this? Its a question of knowing where to start.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_dotnet.html) on code.google.com on how to build a .NET app for the Google Apps Marketplace that uses DotNetOpenAuth to perform authentication and authorization.
It should help you getting started.